# Is there a way to put WHERE for both databases while using JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, let's call them DB1 and DB2, which I want to JOIN, but filter both of them.

Example(using it in PHP):

```
public function PersonalData($example)
{
    $this->getDBConnection('cms1', 'cms_neu');

    $sql = "SELECT id1, name1, status1, section1  
            FROM DB1 pd
            WHERE id1 = '".$example['id1']."' 
            AND status1 = 1
            JOIN DB2 dp ON pd.section1 = dp.section2
            WHERE dp.type2 = 30";
    $query = $this->dbh->query($sql);
    $result = $query->fetchAll();

    return $result;
}
```

I can't properly explain what I need even for myself, thus I can't really find the solution

I've tried using JOIN and adding WHERE/AND after it but I don't think that that will work.

So it should select every id1 and change value of section1 to what it is in section2 based on type2 being exactly 30.

Comment: `JOIN` comes before your `WHERE` clause - https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join. And I think you mean _tables_, not _databases_.

Comment: Correct and correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL statements consists of clauses, which include `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`.  And these should appear in a `SELECT` statement in this order.

`JOIN` is an operator in the `FROM` clause.

So, your query should look like:

```
SELECT id1, name1, status1, section1  
FROM DB1 pd JOIN
     DB2 dp
     ON pd.section1 = dp.section2
WHERE pd.id1 = '".$example['id1']."' AND
      pd.status1 = 1 AND
      dp.type2 = 30;
```

Notes:

- *Learn to use parameters*!  Don't munge query strings with parameter values.  This just leads to code risks and hard-to-debug errors.
- Qualify all column references, particularly when the query contains more than on table reference.

Comment: So even if I wanted to add type2 = 50 also in the query, it would work?

Comment: @asobak . . . You can add more conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I mean it confuses me since both tables has ID but not the same values, and I only need to use from DB1, section2 should replace every ID from DB1 only with 30 and 50 values that are specified in DB2.

Comment: @asobak . . . This seems to have nothing to do with the question you asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.